# Restoring purchased issues for Newsstand based app subscription

Tags: objective-c, ios5, storekit

I am developing a newsstand based application. I have read a lot of tutorials to understand the logic behind newsstand subscription based application. But still I am not clear with all the ideas of Newsstand application.

My doubt is that if I make a subscription based purchase from one of my device and also I have another device too. If I need to download my previous purchases to my new device, how this can be done? When I referred the following site, it says that restoring is possible.

http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/using-newsstand-subscriptions-on-multiple-devices/

Can anyone brief about the procedures happening while restoring the previous purchases.

The other thing I would like to know is that consider the situation, user had subscribed to 1 month and again if the user tries to subscribe for any other option like 6 months, 1 year, etc. How this situation should be handled? Do Apple itself manages this situation or do need to handle it manually?

Thanks in advance